# Swap/reordering select options using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating items reordering form. This is my html fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/10733/)
Im considering few approaches:

1. Example: If C(3rd) selected as 1st. 1st item should automatically be changed as selected in 3rd place: `1: A; 2: B; 3: C => 1: C; 2: B; 3: A`

or

2. If C(3rd) selected as 1st, all items pushed further one slot (as If C was inserted into 1st place, pushing everything +1 order: `1: A; 2: B; 3: C 4: D => 1: C; 2: A; 3: B, 4: D`

2-nd approach is actually better, but seems harder to do.

Any ideas where should I start?

Edit:

Can't find a way to get select id, for select box, which needs swapping.

Comment: Why don't you use a multiple select list with up and down button for user to change the order?

Comment: Because I couldn't find one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060731/select-box-for-ordering-items-in-form

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/AJzMh/